# GKE Mulitple networking

Tags: kubernetes, google-cloud-platform, google-kubernetes-engine, gke-networking

In the GKE documentation I couldn't find a reference for supporting Multus or IPVLAN attachment. All I find is related to Anthos on bare metal.

Could you please give us some indications how multi-networking is supported for Pods running on GKE?

First can I have GKE nodes with multiple NIC's attached?

Answer (score 1):

It is not currently supported but it's on the roadmap for sometime next year.

Comment: Thanks a lot Gari , is there anyway to add GKE nodes with multiple NICs ?

Comment: Also , is there an alterntavie way currently avaialble ?

Is it possible to have Anthos on GCP  while having the compute instances running with 2 NICs ?